# How to square a sheet from 2 grip points

Tags: computer-vision, rotation, alignment, square, motion

I have a new project on hand and some help will be appreciated.

The idea is to square or align a plastic sheet using two clamping grippers controlled by servo motors.

The sheet is being gripped from two points left hand gripper and right hand gripper. We got it pretty much working but to achieve that I have to take 3 or 4 pictures and execute the correction after each picture. The way we are doing it is to take a picture and get the Y positions looking for a target that can be a square or a circle etc.. and then move the gripper to the reference position ( origin on the vision ). to match the Y position of the circle or square shape whit the camera reference position.

And with only 1 or 2 pictures the accuracy is not very good. I think the reason why this is happening is because when the servo moves the left-hand gripper to the reference position the other side (right-hand ) goes out of position.

The vision system we are using is the  FH .

Has anyone done something similar before?. If yes how do you do to move the right distance, to get the sheet square?.

Please see the pictures.

Thanks

The expected is to have the sheet align within a precision of 0.2mm.